# how to assign a value to variable and get the return value of output in single line

Tags: shell, if-statement

I have below line in my script

```
script_list=`ssh@hostip ls -A /directory 2>/dev/null`
```

Is there a way to use that in if condition, so that i can get the script_list variable assigned or handle the failure scenario in else condition

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check the automatic variable `$?` in the next line:

```
script_list=$( ssh ... )
rc=$?
if [[ $rc -ne 0 ]]; then
    ...something is wrong...
fi
```

This works because the exit code of `ssh` is the exit code of the command it ran remotely if `ssh` itself could be executed successfully. But usually, you don't care which part of the command chain failed, it's good enough to know that any part (the local `ssh` *or* the remote command failed).

Answer (score 0):

No problem, just do it. An assignment is perfectly fine as a command (by command I mean the thing which can come after an `if`).

```
if asdf=$(echo test1; exit 1); then
    echo "SUCCESS1: $asdf"
fi
if asdf=$(echo test0; exit 0); then
    echo "SUCCESS0: $asdf"
fi
```